# Can I wall mount this pedestal sink?

Tags: bathroom, sink

Is there a way to mount this sink on the wall?
On the right side of the back of the sink, the outline of the 4th hole is molded onto the sink and I thought perhaps I can drill into that spot to reveal a hole that would allow me to hang it the sink on the wall.

I cannot access the holes on top from the front of the sink but it seems i could hang the top two holes on suitable supports and drill stainless screws from the front in the bottom two holes

The backing is plenty strong.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: What is the material of the sink--ceramic or fiberglass/epoxy? You cannot drill into or through china (ceramic). You need a special purpose designed kit to mount a pedestal lavatory. Where did you get this sink? A mounting kit should have come with it or been offered as an option for an additional charge. Did any instructions come with it?

Comment: Are the upper holes accessible from below?

Comment: the holes in the back are to prevent the sink from leaning away from the wall .... they are not for supporting the sink weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up fabricating some huge metal brackets to "hang" the sink from (there was an edge protruding where there was grab) and drilled those in the wall (that wasn't real tile by the way)

And adding 2 super thick "L" brackets from the wall to the flat underside of the sink.

It's pretty solid now.

Answer (score 2):

Hung sinks typically have brackets that connect high up on the sink. (This makes sense, because that's where you'd want to resist leverage.)

If you could somehow fashion a 2 piece bracket, it's likely** (see below) that you could drill into the porcelain (without breaking it), and attach it using sturdy toggles.

Unfortunately, it looks like you have a wall that's already tiled, so you don't have any depth into which to set this bracket. So unless you want to bust up your wall, I'd suggest you stick with the pedestal. Or get a deliberately designed sink that'll have the recess for the bracket built into the sink.

Porcelain is an inconsistent product, so failure is always an option. But, a diamond hole saw, used according to instructions (speed, spraying with water while drilling) will usually drill a successful hole. Plus, in this setting, a major blowout would probably be limited to the invisible back surface, which would mean that the sink is back to being used as a pedestal, which doesn't seem like such a great loss to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd trust the integrity of the back panel even if you could hang it successfully. The weight of the sink alone is a concern in that use case, and the inevitable clumsy person hanging on it will certainly result in catastrophe. If you were able to get suitably large washers inside the upper holes, but....

The only way I'd mount this would be using steel brackets from underneath--not fastened to the back panel or otherwise. L-brackets bolted to the framing and extending under some part of the underside of the sink at least 2/3 the depth of the sink might do. You'd need to use silicone or some other adhesive to keep it in stable and in place, along with lag screws through the lower holes.